# Can I open Passbook passes?

Tags: file-format

Sometimes I have the option to download a **.pkpass** to my phone when I buy a ticket. The **.pkpass** is the file format for **Apple's Passbook**, an app not available in Windows Phone.

Is there any app that can open **.pkpass** files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Windows Phone 8.1

The Wallet in an early Developer Preview included support for .pkpass but the later versions does not have the support (the Wallet still support the passes but the support for the .pkpass extension seems to be missing).

See below for other ways to open .pkpass.

#### Windows Phone 8.0

There are third-party apps available like [Wallet Pass](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=61e56c4f-08e0-4427-af8d-7253603353cb), [All my passes](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=f9a1ba90-033b-4821-be74-ff5cf0b2ae15) and [Pass Wallet](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=078d595a-565c-4545-aeab-e15dd182b8fc).

#### Windows Phone 7

This Windows Phone version doesn't have the Wallet app nor has support for third-party apps.

Comment: Additionally, if you don't want to use multiple wallet Apps, you can also use [Passbook Converter](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/passbook-converter/9wzdncrfjjsg), which converts .pkpass on the fly and adds it to your wallet automatically. It also has a free test version that allows you to do 10 such conversions.